# Compose BottomNavigation - How to disable BottomNavigationTransition animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomnavigationview

Inside the Compose BottomNavigation class, there is a BottomNavigationTransition that changes the selected/unselected tab color with an animation progress.

```
@Composable
private fun BottomNavigationTransition(
    activeColor: Color,
    inactiveColor: Color,
    selected: Boolean,
    content: @Composable (animationProgress: Float) -> Unit
) {
    val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (selected) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = BottomNavigationAnimationSpec
    )

    val color = lerp(inactiveColor, activeColor, animationProgress)

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides color.copy(alpha = 1f),
        LocalContentAlpha provides color.alpha,
    ) {
        content(animationProgress)
    }
}

private val BottomNavigationAnimationSpec = TweenSpec<Float>(
    durationMillis = 300,
    easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
)
```

This is causing an unwanted behaviour in bottom navigation. When a tab is selected, for a very short period of time, the tab is filled with inactiveColor first, and then after 300ms it is filled with activeColor. Here is slowed down GIF of this. As you can see the tab is first filled with BLUE color, and then it becomes RED.

[image]

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: There is a flag called "alwaysShowLabel" in the BottomNavigation composable method. Try setting that flag to true so that the icon will not be animated.